# Does VS Code Vim have an equivalent to Atom's vim-mode-plus toggle-preset-occurrence?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim, vim-mode-plus

I currently use Atom with the vim-mode-plus extension as my text editor, and I have been recommended to try VS Code (with the vim extension). I am enjoying it so far, but am missing the ability to select all the occurences of the word under the cursor. I find this useful to change/delete variables in only a few lines.

If I try the VS Code way of using `ctrl+shift+l` to select all occurences, as soon as I press either `c` or `d` then it applies this action to all occurences throughout the document. Ideally, I would like to be able to press `c2j` to only affect the occurences in the current and next line down.

Thanks.

Comment: This is exactly what has kept me from switching as well. But with the announcement of the sunset of Atom.... I fear my learned shortcuts are going to be getting me into trouble very soon. I hope someone is able/willing to port some of this "advanced" vim mode plus functionality!

Comment: Man I keep coming back to this post hoping there's been some movement in this direction! Wish I had the time myself to contribute to making it happen, especially now that I have to use VS Code.